# Android NDK, Navit

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am building navit with standalone tools from NDK r7. 
./configure is able to pass the compiler test.

However when I run make, I get the following error w.r.t headers.

It is looking for machine/internal_types.h which is not available either with NDK C headers or standard gcc headers. Is this due to incorrect compiler options?

Error Log below.

> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sateesh/navit/navit/fib-1.1'
>   /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile
>   i686-android-linux-gcc -nostdlib -march=i686 -mstackrealign
>   -L/opt/ndk_x86_r7/lib  -L. -I/opt/ndk_x86_r7/usr/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -D_GNU_SOURCE -ffast-math -I../../intl/ -MT fib.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fib.Tpo -c -o fib.lo fib.c
>
> libtool: compile:  i686-android-linux-gcc -nostdlib -march=i686
>   -mstackrealign -L/opt/ndk_x86_r7/lib -L. -I/opt/ndk_x86_r7/usr/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -D_GNU_SOURCE -ffast-math -I../../intl/ -MT fib.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fib.Tpo -c fib.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fib.o
>
> In file included from
>   /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/limits.h:86,
>                    from /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/include-fixed/limits.h:122,
>                    from /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7,
>                    from /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-android-linux/4.4.3/include-fixed/limits.h:11,
>                    from fib.c:33:
>
> /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/sys/limits.h:44:36: error:
>   machine/internal_types.h: No such file or directory
>
> /opt/ndk_x86_r7/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/sys/limits.h:47:28:
>   **error: machine/limits.h: No such file or directory**

Comment: What API level have you chose for the toolchain? All APIs below android-9 are broken for x86 arch.

Comment: I have chosen API level 8, since my device is running on 8. Will try with 9 and post the results. Thanks.

Comment: @andrey Tried with API level 9, it builds fine.